# Counting sum of only distinct values while displaying other columns

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm trying to create an alert using promql/prometheus but having trouble generating the proper time series. In K8s, my objective is to display any code/version mismatch for a particular app sitting in multiple clusters. By using count, any app with a value greater than 1 would tell me that there are > 1 version deployed. Currently my query will generate the following:

`count(kube_deployment_labels{label_app=~".*"}) by (label_version, label_app)`

```
| label_app |  label_version  |  Value #A |
-------------------------------------------
| app_1     |   0.0.111       |     2     |
| app_1     |   0.0.222       |     1     |
| app_2     |   0.0.111       |     2     |
| app_2     |   0.0.222       |     1     |
| app_3     |   0.0.111       |     3     |
```

The values on the 4th column represent the # of said code (*label_version*) deployed in each cluster; for example, **app_1** & **app_2** has version **0.0.111** deployed in two clusters & **0.0.222** deployed in one cluster, but **app_3** has the same version deployed in all three clusters.

My end goal is to only count distinct *label_version* and have the time series populate in this way:

```
| label_app |  Value #A  |
 -------------------------
| app_1     |      2     |
| app_2     |      2     |
| app_3     |      1     |
```

Executing `(count(group by(label_version)kube_deployment_labels{label_app=~".*"}))`  gives me the correct *Value* but I'd like to list out all the apps associated to the *Value* as well. I've tried a variety of grouping but was unsuccessful.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply one more `count by` over your previous result.

```
count(
 count(
  kube_deployment_labels{label_app=~".*"}
 ) by (label_version, label_app)
) by (label_app)
```

will return number of `label_version`s associated with each `label_app`.

Somewhat similar query can be seen in this [demo](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=go_info&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=count(alertmanager_alerts_received_total)%20by%20(status%2Cversion)&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h&g2.expr=count(%0A%20%20count(%0A%20%20%20%20alertmanager_alerts_received_total%0A%20%20)%20by%20(status%2Cversion)%0A)by(status)&g2.tab=1&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=1h).